# Why i cannot call Set method with Optional<> :the method setName is undefined for the type Optional?

Tags: spring-boot, java-8

this is My ProfileService:

i am trying to set name and lastname in the update method but i couldn't because the return type of the getProfile method is an optional and it says that :the method setNom() is undefined for the type Optional.

```
 @Service
  public class ProfileService {

@Autowired
private ProfileRepository repository;

// get profile by id
public Optional<Profile> getProfile(Long id) {
    Optional<Profile> profile = repository.findById(id);
    if (profile == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return profile;
}

// save profile
public Profile saveProfile(Profile profile) {
    return repository.save(profile);
}

// delete profile
public Map<String, Boolean> deleteProfile(Long id) {
    Optional<Profile> profile2 = getProfile(id);
    Map<String, Boolean> result = new HashMap<>();
    if (profile2 == null) {
        result.put("deleted", false);
        return result;
    }
    repository.deleteById(id);
    result.put("deleted", true);
    return result;
}

// update Profile
public Profile updateProfile(Profile profileDetails, Long id) {
    Optional<Profile> profile = getProfile(id);
    if (profile == null) {
        return null;
    }
    profile.setNom(profileDetails.getNom());
    profile.setPrenom(profileDetails.getPrenom());
    Profile updatedProfile = repository.save(profileDetails);
    return updatedProfile;
}

 }
```

Comment: You are using Optional incorrectly. There is (or should not be) any reason to compare an Optional to null: `if (profile == null)`. If you want to use nullable types, you may as well not use Optional at all. Also, an instance of Optional is not an instance of the type it contains. If you want the wrapped value you can use `orElseThrow()`, e.g. `profile.orElseThrow().setNom(whatever)`

Comment: Thank you for replying i really appreciate it .so if i put Optional i should  erase this line :if (profile ==null)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `profile.get().setNom()` in case the profile optional has value

A better option would be to use @Michaels suggestion from the comments, if your Java version allows it.

Comment: Prefer `orElseThrow()` from Java 10+. Java designers have conceded that calling it `get()` was a mistake

Comment: Thank you guys for replying ,i have change it to get() and it worked.About .orElseThrow i am using it in the constructor when i am calling getProfile Method of the service between my Java version is 8